# Cannot unzip zip file with password created by winrar in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, zip

I have a zip file made in Windows 7 with winrar which opens with the password just fine in Windows- but both Ubuntu unzip from GUI and python zipfile utility running in Ubuntu cannot unzip the file with the correct password.

Interestingly, running zipfile in python on Windows also fails at extracting the files, with the same error (bad password). What could I be missing?

Comment: I got a similar problem few days ago with windows 10 and 7-zip. Even in .zip or .7z format, my Ubuntu PC wasn't able to extract the files if they were compressed with password protection.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a workaround - I installed 7zip on Ubuntu using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
sudo apt-get install p7zip-rar
```

What I do to extract the files is to import subprocess in python and use the shell to extract the files for me.